# Angular Change the src property when selected an option

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a select with the options - male, female and other. I want if I select male, a picture of a male to be shown. If I select a female, a picture of a female to be shown and etc.

HTML code:

```
 <label>Choose gender:</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="gender" name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
    <option value="o">Other</option>
  </select>
    <img [src]="imageUrl" >
```

In TS file:

```
gender: string;
imageUrl: string;
constructor() {
  this.imageUrl = 'https://api.drupal.org/sites/default/files/default-avatar.png'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this to have subscribed to the `(change)` event and in the event handler function write your logic

**Markup**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="gender" name="gender" id="gender" (change)='onGenderChange()'>
```

**Component**

```
public onGenderChange() {
    switch(this.gender) {
        case 'm': 
           this.imageUrl = 'url1';
           break;
        case 'f';
           this.imageUrl = 'url2'
           break;
        default:
           this.imageUrl = 'defaultUrl';
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<label>Choose gender:</label>
<select [(ngModel)]="gender" name="gender" id="gender" (ngModelChange)="genderChange($event)">
  <option value="m">Male</option>
  <option value="f">Female</option>
  <option value="o">Other</option>
</select>
<br/>
<img *ngIf="imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl" >
```

**typescript**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  gender: string;
  imageUrl: string;

  genderChange($e) {
    if(this.gender == 'm') {
      this.imageUrl = "https://api.drupal.org/sites/default/files/default-avatar-male.png";
    } else if(this.gender == 'f') {
      this.imageUrl = "https://api.drupal.org/sites/default/files/default-avatar-female.png";
    } else {
      this.imageUrl = "https://api.drupal.org/sites/default/files/default-avatar-other.png";
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-95yuxy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)